# Puppet : exec[] : wget returned 8 instead of 0

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am completely new to Puppet and this is my first time writing code in puppet. I want to get a `tar.gz` file and then untar it to create the folder.

Here is my code:

```
file{ "${::filename}.tar.gz":
   ensure => 'file',
   mode   => '0644',
   notify => Exec['untar-file'],
}

exec{ 'download-file' :
   command => "wget URL_FOR_TAR_GZ",
   cwd     => "PATH_WHERE_TO_STORE",
   user    => "my_name",
   group   => "our company name",
}

exec { 'untar-file':
   command => "/bin/tar -xzvf tar_file_name",
   cwd     => "file_path",
   creates => "foldername_to_be_createdc",
   user    => "my_name",
   group   => "our company name",
   require => Exec['download-file']
}
```

As soon as I run this I get an error:

> wget returned 8 instead of one of [0]" and "/Exec[download-file]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What happens when you execute the `wget` command on the node manually? Also, why are you creating the tarball with a `file` resource and then attempting to download it afterward with the `exec`? Furthermore, the `file` resource can download files for you: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/file.html#file-attribute-source

Comment: Status code 8 says something is wrong on the server [Exit Status](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html). Not sure the version of `wget` you are running so I took what Google offered up.

Comment: @Matt: If I try to execute wget on command line I can download the file properly.   Ken: does it mean I need to change wget version?

Comment: @Matt: because otherwise I get and error asking to define path to the command saying "Validation failed". Also I am using http url to download the file so I cannot use source in file

Comment: Ok then work on fixing the double resource and missing path to wget and see what happens afterward.